# React Auth0 (Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, auth0

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it. at withAuthenticationRequired

```
export const AdminRoute = ({ component: Component, navbar: Navbar, ...props }) => {
console.log('props==>', props.dynamicClass);
let dynamicClass = `wrapper ${props.dynamicClass}`
return (
    <Route
        {...props}
        render={(props) => (
            <MediaQuery minWidth={800}>
                {(matches) => {
                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <WithAuthenticationRequired>
                                <div className={dynamicClass}>
                                    <Navbar />
                                    <Component {...props} />
                                    <Footer />
                                </div>
                            </WithAuthenticationRequired>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    );
                }}
            </MediaQuery>
        )}
    />
);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are passing into `MediaQuery` is a function definition (as state by the error).

The components you are returning will only be returned once this function is called. Following is one way to force the call(does not work with arrow functions):

```
<MediaQuery minWidth={800}>
    {(function (matches) {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <WithAuthenticationRequired>
                    <div className={dynamicClass}>
                        <Navbar />
                        <Component {...props} />
                        <Footer />
                    </div>
                </WithAuthenticationRequired>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    })()}
</MediaQuery>;
```

Or you can do something like creating a new function that returns the components you need, and then calling that function within `<MediaQuery>`:

```
<MediaQuery minWidth={800}>{getFragment(matches)}</MediaQuery>;

const getFragment = (matches) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <WithAuthenticationRequired>
                <div className={dynamicClass}>
                    <Navbar />
                    <Component {...props} />
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </WithAuthenticationRequired>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Comment: not working for me. This is a auth0 example